# Algorithm for deducing values

Tags: logic

I have a group of logical conditions and need to deduce values that would **NOT** satisfy them.  For example:

1. `City != New York && Location = Museum`
2. `City = New York && Location = Store`
3. `City != New York && Location != Subway`
4. `Elevation = 100'`

So some values that would **NOT** satisfy any of those conditions are:

- `City: New York, Location: Museum, Elevation: 110'`
- `City: Moscow, Location: Subway, Elevation: 110'`

I just need to derive values, any values, that will fail to satisfy all conditions.  (Application: Generating manual tests.)

It's easy to figure out values to violate any one condition, but I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to generate values that will violate them all.  I have all the logical conditions in a data format (JSON, e.g. `{ key: 'City', operator: '=', referenceValue = 'New York' }`).

---

This solution worked for me, but I'm not making it an answer because it's not super-elegant and I'm not sure it would work in all cases.

1. Create a value hash for each key, populating it with all possible values for that key.
2. Each value for each key is marked ALLOWED initially, but can later be marked CONTINGENT or DISALLOWED. (I created a ValueDisposition class to manage this.)
3. Find relevant conditions for each key, and analyze their effect on values.  For example analyzing condition 4 above for `elevation` would mark `100'` as DISALLOWED (because we are looking to find data that violate all the given conditions). Analyzing condition 2 above for `City` would mark `New York` as CONTINGENT because it is only a valid value if the contingent condition `Location = Store` is violated (I record contingent conditions in the ValueDisposition class as well).
4. Do a first pass finding an ALLOWED value for as many keys as possible.
5. Do a second pass on CONTINGENT values, violating the contingent conditions to derive acceptable value-sets (for example, with `New York` it's easy to violate `Location = Store`). I was able to do this easily for all of my condition-sets, but this could get challenging (requiring recursion?) if you had contingent conditions involving multiple keys.

Comment: Is each of the conditions either one simple predicate or the conjunction of two predicates? Are there other forms?

Comment: Yes, they are either simple predicates or the conjunction of multiple predicates (never more than 5 I'd say).

Comment: Have you heard of [boolean satisfiability problem (SAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) and SAT solver?

Comment: Unless most of the conditions involve only at most two predicates, your problem is likely to be really hard, **NP**-hard.

Comment: I hadn't.  If my problem is equivalent to SAT, then it seems like randomized assignment of the values (the PPSZ algorithm) is the fastest way to look for a solution?

Comment: I am not an expert on the SAT solvers. Let us hope others pitch in. You can give some of them a try in the meantime.

Comment: Randomized assignment is only the fastest "in theory" for SAT. Solvers using some kind of (non-provable, very bad exponential) heuristics are usually very fast for many (industrial) problems, not so much for random problems.
I would recommend to convert your problem into DIMACs form and feed it to any SAT solver (binary or in the programming language of your choice).

Comment: I'm still not sure if my problem is equivalent to SAT.  Trying to work the above out naively on a piece of paper, I solved it by: 1) discarding variables constrained by only one condition (`elevation` above), 2) drawing a grid with the two multiply-constrained variables (`city` and `location`) on the x and y axis, 3) working through the conditions to identify grid squares corresponding to values allowed by the conjunctions, 4) choosing any one of the remaining boxes to find violating values.  Could this work as an algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicated, if the goal is to invent fictional cities, and you allow more three or more conjuncts in a condition, then any SAT problem is reducible to your problem.

Depending on the type of constraints, this is probably a more general problem, called "SAT Modulo Theories" or SMT for short. It's the boolean satisfiability problem, plus the theory of whatever your constraints are.

For example, if you allow inequalities:

```
Elevation < 200
```

You now need to decide what kinds of constraints those are. If elevation is an integer, and you allow constraints between properties (e.g. number of subway stations is less than the number of suburbs), then solving the problem is, in general, an [integer programming feasibility problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

But chances are that you don't need to worry about that for your scale. If we allow the [closed-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption), in the sense that the set of city names and locations etc is fixed, then backtracking search is probably good enough. A small Prolog program will do the job.

Here, I used GNU Prolog, and attached the finite domain solver for elevation:

```
city(new_york).
city(moscow).
city(london).
city(paris).

location(museum).
location(store).
location(subway).
location(grand_bazaar).

% The lowest city in the world is Jericho, and the highest city
% is La Paz.
elevation(Elevation) :- fd_domain(Elevation, -846, 11975).

satisfying_cities(City, Location, Elevation) :-
    city(City),
    location(Location),
    elevation(Elevation),
    (City = new_york ; \+ Location = museum),
    (\+ City = new_york ; \+ Location = store),
    (City = new_york ; Location = subway),
    (Elevation #\= 100).
```

And running the query:

```
?- satisfying_cities(City, Location, Elevation).
```

gives some answers, the first of which is:

```
City = new_york
Elevation = _#0(0..99:101..127@)
Location = museum
```

The FD constraint on elevation is a little hard to read, but it's essentially saying that any elevation between 0 and 99 or 101 and 127 will do.